# Cannot alter MYSQL Table (stuck in a invalid default value loop)

Tags: mysql, alter-table, default-value

Some how I have 2 columns with incorrect default values.
Not sure how it got created in the first place as I imported the db from another source.

Problem now is, I cannot make any changes to the table cause MYSQL will complain:

> MySQL said: Invalid default value for 'campaign_start_date'

if I tried adding a column.

But when I try changing the `DEFAULT VALUE` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `campaign_start_date`, it complains `campaign_end_date` has an invalid default value.

So I'm stuck in a loop that doesn't allow me to make any changes to the table.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Could you post the create table for this table?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try changing both columns defaults at the same time:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable 
    CHANGE campaign_start_date campaign_start_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CHANGE campaign_end_date campaign_end_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thanks! I found another solution is to change the `sql_mode`. Just remove the `NO_ZERO_DATE` field in `my.cnf`, so MYSQL will stop complaining.

Comment: (Note:  Before 5.6.5, such defaults would not be allowed.)